# Redirect during unscheduled maintainence

Tags: php, mysql

Occasionally our server experiences database connection issues and we want to temporary redirect users when this happens. What would be the best way to redirect users to a maintenance page?

Something like

```
if (!$db) {
    header("Location: /maintainence/index.php, TRUE, 503");
    exit();
}
```

or

```
if (!$db) {
  header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
  header('Status: 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable');
  header('Retry-After: 3600'); // in seconds
  include_once "maintainence/index.php";
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a small side note: it is maintenance instead of maintainence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to respond is with a relevant HTTP status code - this solves the problems of REST, AJAX and search engine carawlers - but some verions of MSIE will hide the information you are sending to the user [if the content is considered too short](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294807).

```
header("Location: /maintainence/index.php, TRUE, 503);
```

Leaving aside the mising quote, you can't do a redirect (30x) and return an error code at the same time. Do it inline as per the 2nd method - BUT ADD AN EXPLICIT EXIT!

Answer (score 1):

You should respond with an appropriate 5xx response code (server error), not with a redirect (which means "the information you requested can be found elsewhere", which it can't). You also can't redirect and issue a 5xx response code at the same time, redirects are all 3xx. So method #2, outputting the 503 with an error page in the body, is the correct response.